# Trying to extract a string using regex

Tags: swift, regex

```
import Foundation
//Functions
//An "amazingly elegant" way of using regex (Why does it need to be a [String], I just need the string!
func matches(of regex:String, in text:String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
let fileName = #"[\w\s\,\.\-]+\.txt"#
let filePath = "/Users/Johnson/Some Text File.txt"
let funckWiktor = matches(of: fileName, in: filePath!)
print(funckWiktor)
//["Some Text File.txt"]
```

I would really love it if I  could  just get the string without the quotation marks. For example:

```
let fileName = #"[\w\s\,\.\-]+\.txt"#
let filePath = "/Users/Johnson/Some Text File.txt"
let funckWiktor = matches(of: fileName, in: filePath!)
print(funckWiktor)
//Some Text File.txt
```

I love the way we can replace regEx matches in Swift like so:

```
let stringOrg = "Hello, I just want the last part of this."
let regEx = #"\w\."#
var finalString = stringOrg.replacingOccurrences(of: regEx, with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

And I  wish there was a way to just find them similar to this:

```
let stringOrg = "Hello, I just want the last part of this."
let regEx = #"\w\."#
let incompleteString = "Something is missing at the end of "
var finalString = incompleteString + stringOrg.findingOccurrences(of: regEx, options: .regularExpression)
//[finalString = "Something is missing at the end of this."]
```

Is there a way to get the clean substring when matching with regEx?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want? Could you add a clear example with input, reg ex and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask:

> Why does it need to be a [String], I just need the string!

That’s because `matches(of:in)` returns an array of all matches (an array that has only one item, in your example). If you only want the first item from that array that is returned, use the `first` method:

```
let fileName = #"[\w\s\,\.\-]+\.txt"#
let filePath = "/Users/Johnson/Some Text File.txt"
if let funckWiktor = matches(of: fileName, in: filePath!).first {
    print(funckWiktor)
}
```

---

Or, just like you have a `match(of:in:)` that mirrors the similarly named `NSRegularExpression` method, you could do the same with `firstMatch`:

```
func firstMatch(of regex: String, in text: String) -> String? {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let result = regex.firstMatch(in: text, range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return result
            .flatMap { Range($0.range, in: text) }
            .flatMap { String(text[$0]) }
    } catch {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Thus:

```
let string = "There are 42 apples and 13 oranges."

if let result = firstMatch(of: #"\d+"#, in: string) {
    print(result)  // 42
}
```

FWIW, while I patterned `firstMatch` after your method, we can simplify it:

```
func firstMatch(of regex: String, in text: String) -> String? {
    text.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression)
        .flatMap { String(text[$0]) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, for the amazing detailed explanation. By the way your simplified method is exactly the type of elegant solution I was looking for!  Now that you pointed out how the first one returns an array, I  can't help but wonder if your simplified method can also do the same with a modification and  still keep it as elegant and free of NSString.

Comment: No, I think you need to keep the `NSRegularExpression`, though, if you’re inviting feedback, I’d (a) make it a `String` extension; (b) I’d make it throw regex errors so caller could differentiate between no matches and regex syntax errors; (c) give it an optional parameter for regex options; and (d) I’d probably go “all in” on the functional patterns. E.g. https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/138ffea5603625830d0970b3022fefdf

Comment: That is simply beautiful, thanks @Rob! Great shout with throwing!

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
    func getMatchingString(pattern: String) -> String {
        var matchedStr = ""
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count)
            
            if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: range) {
                let found : NSRange = match.range
                
                let start = String.Index(utf16Offset: found.location, in: self)
                let end = String.Index(utf16Offset: found.length, in: self)
                
                matchedStr = String(self[start..<end])
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        return matchedStr
    }
}
```

Try this.

let substring = filePath.getMatchingString(fileName)